# On Row selection is firing the event only once Primefaces data table

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable, row, selection

On Row selection is firing only once .. 
I am displaying results using p:datatable, when I click on a row, the corresponding onRowSelect Method is calling .. But it is working for first time, later on the event is not being triggered.

```
<p:dataTable id="resultsTable"  var="details" paginator="true" rows="10"  
 value="#{memberSearchBean.memberDetails}" 
 emptyMessage="No Records exists for this member"
 selection="#{memberSearchBean.selectedMember}"    selectionMode="single"
 rowKey="#{details.coverNumber}" 
  >

 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{memberSearchBean.onRowSelect}"  update=":memberSearchForm:displayselectedMember" oncomplete="PF('displayselectedMember').show()" /> 


    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  

        MemberDetailsBean mb =  (MemberDetailsBean) event.getObject(); 

 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.. I have searched alot but i did not get correct answer..

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript is running into an error when it executes `PF('displayselectedMember').show()`, because you have not defined the widgetVar `displayselectedMember`. You have it as an ID, which the `PF` function doesn't recognize. When JavaScript hits an error, it stops executing, which is preventing your function call (via AJAX).

I recommend debugging with the developer tools in Chrome or with Firebug in Firefox. Either of these would have outputted this error for you in the console.

Also, note: the `PF(widgetVar)` notation doesn't appear to work in version 3.x; it may new to 4.x. If you're using 3.x, call it like this: `widgetVar.function()`.

Comment: You are correct. When I removed   PF('displayselectedMember').show() , It worked ..and event is firing all the times.. But I am not getting the correct row which ever i selected.. not sure ..why always getting only one row details ..for eg:  MemberDetailsBean mb =  (MemberDetailsBean) event.getObject(); Where my  MemberDetailsBean is one of the object of managed Bean MemberSearchBean

Comment: IMO you should ask that question separately, as it's not in scope for this one.